# How can I rewrite the protobuf scheam with flatbuffer schema?

Tags: protocol-buffers, flatbuffers

For example , Here is the protobuf schema code, I want to rewrite them by flatbuffer schema? what is the code like ?

```
    message Xx {
    required uint32 id = 1;
    optional string name = 2;
    message Yy {
        optional string name = 1;
    }
    repeated Yy y = 3;
}
```

thank you my bro.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

FlatBuffers has .proto translation built-in, try `flatc --proto myschema.proto`, and you will get the corresponding .fbs file.

In your case though, you have nested message definitions, which FlatBuffers doesn't support. So first change your .proto such `message Yy` is moved outside of `message Xx`. Also give it a package name. You'll get:

```
table Yy {
  name:string;
}

table Xx {
  id:uint (required);
  name:string;
  y:[Yy];
}
```

EDIT: FlatBuffers now supports translating even nested .proto definitions.

Comment: Thank you. But I recommended maybe FlatBuffers support the nested message. Because existing message in ProtoBuffers have many nest mode.

Comment: It is something with the code when I compiler the source. The compiler give the error about 
  only non-scalar fields in tables may be 'required'
And I think it is a Bug ??? Do you ?

Comment: Yes, that's a bug, please file an issue on github. For now, just delete the `(required)`.

Comment: OK, thank you Aardappel , I will have an issue on github right now.